# Download manager simultaneous download, missing description

Tags: android

I use DownloadManager to download files for my app. I see few problems.
Sometimes I see simultaneous download - 2 files are downloading at same time(at least I see 2 notifications). Other problem is that for some files I see description and for some not.

How DownloadManager works? Is it possible download more files at the same time? Or what can cause this problems? Can it be because app is sometimes killed, restarted while downloading?

This is code which I use:

```
Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
request.setTitle(episodeTitle);
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
request.setDescription("Episode is downloading");
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file));

downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

As you can see on image bellow, second notification contains description, first not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are downloading both files to the same folder.
Try to download files each in a separate folder.
That should help.